# Creating a custom keras layer that can randomly select k length from the first dimension of the input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom layer in Keras that each time picks `k` random samples from the `inputs` tensor.

Something like that:

```
import random

class RandomKAggregator(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RandomKAggregator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.k = 3

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs[[random.randint(0, len(inputs) - 1) for _ in range(self.k)]]
```

The goal is to pick `k` samples across the first dimension. For example, if the `inputs` tensor's shape is `[500, 32, 32, 3]` it should return a tensor of shape `[k, 32, 32, 3]`, where each call for the layer it should pick different `k` elements.

The above implementation returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`.
I tried to use `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd` but couldn't resolve that.

- What is the right way to achieve the desired result?
- Also, would like to understand how TensorFlow handles indexing and how should I use lists of indices with tensors, say I want to pick `[6,3,1,0]` from `my_tensor`, and why `my_tensor[[6,3,1,0]]` doesn't work for me?

Comment: List of indices does not work in `python` `lists` so why should it work in `tensorflow`? For a great tutorial on `slicing` in `tensorflow`: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor_slicing

Comment: About the random function: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers#interaction_with_tffunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know about slicing ([link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1740577), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011123/1740577)):

```
>>> tns = tf.random.uniform((3,2,2,3))
>>> tns
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.2313137 , 0.17192566],
         [0.25301564, 0.20687258]],
        [[0.5184531 , 0.49340045],
         [0.41016984, 0.6423464 ]]],
       [[[0.57849526, 0.8964175 ],
         [0.86068404, 0.28210032]],
        [[0.96660316, 0.66522324],
         [0.74370325, 0.2124871 ]]],
       [[[0.24575269, 0.7576513 ],
         [0.6213573 , 0.80739546]],
        [[0.79363906, 0.16595817],
         [0.42819571, 0.05265415]]]], dtype=float32)>

>>> tns[1:3, ...]
# Or
>>> tns[1:3, :, :, :]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.57849526, 0.8964175 ],
         [0.86068404, 0.28210032]],
        [[0.96660316, 0.66522324],
         [0.74370325, 0.2124871 ]]],
       [[[0.24575269, 0.7576513 ],
         [0.6213573 , 0.80739546]],
        [[0.79363906, 0.16595817],
         [0.42819571, 0.05265415]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Example Code: *(for generating random number you can use [`numpy.random.randint(start, end, num_number)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class RandomKAggregator(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, k=3):
    super(RandomKAggregator, self).__init__()
    self.k = k


  def call(self, inputs):
    rnd = np.random.randint(0, len(inputs), 1)[0]
    return inputs[rnd:rnd+self.k, ...]

layer = RandomKAggregator(k=10)
layer(tf.random.uniform((500,32,32,3))).shape
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([10, 32, 32, 3])
```

**Edit, How pick `k random elements`: *(Ask in comments)***

- We can use [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) and return k random selected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class RandomKAggregator(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, k=3):
    super(RandomKAggregator, self).__init__()
    self.k = k


  def call(self, inputs):
    rnd = np.random.randint(0, len(inputs), self.k)
    return tf.gather_nd(inputs, rnd.reshape(-1,1))

layer = RandomKAggregator(k=10)
layer(tf.random.uniform((500,32,32,3))).shape
# TensorShape([10, 32, 32, 3])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! but if I understand right the code above it would give me `k` consequent elements while I would like to pick `k` random elements. Am I getting it right? Any modification that can result in the desired outcome?